# Displaying variables in view from the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to display these values from the controller to the view

Here is a snippet of my controller function:

```
        $i = 0;

        foreach($data['main']->result() as $list):

           $list_id = $list[$i]['check_id'];

           //I concatinate the 'extra' and $i so it would have a unique name
           $data['extra'.$i] = $this->MyModel->getExtra($list_id);

           $i++;

        endforeach;

        //I store it on data so I would know the max number in the view
        $data['max'] = $i;

        $this->load->view('Main/viewList',$data);
```

No errors there. Also checked the variables if all are successfully stored.

I would like now to display it on the view.

```
                <?php
                  for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {

                    foreach(($extra.$i)->result() as $list):
                      echo $list->name;

                    endforeach;
                  }
                ?>
```

`$extra.$i` doesnt work on the view. It has an parsing error of `unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from

```
<?php
     for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
         foreach(($extra.$i)->result() as $list):
                echo $list->name;
                endforeach;
     }
?>
```

to

```
<?php
         for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
             $extra = ${'extra' . $i};
             foreach($extra->result() as $list):
                    echo $list->name;
                    endforeach;
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: @guwop69: hope this helps

Comment: ${...} is a variable variables